# Dynamically allow domains for CORS

Tags: node.js, cors

I am running node app with list of whitelisted frontend domains under nginx. Allowed domains are defined in .env file.

app.js:

```
app.use(cors());
```

cors.js:

```
const cors = require('cors');

const whitelist = process.env.CORS_DOMAINS.split(',');

module.exports = (enabled = true) =>
    (req, res, next) => {
        const options = {
            origin(origin, callback) {
                if (!origin) {
                    callback(null, true);
                    return;
                }
                const originIsWhitelisted = enabled ? whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 : true;
                if (originIsWhitelisted) {
                    console.log('cors runs');
                    callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
                    return;
                }
                callback({
                    statusCode: 401,
                    error: 'Not allowed',
                });
            },
        };
        return cors(options)(req, res, next);
    };
```

How can I update whitelisted domains when app is already running?
I have list of domains in the database but don't want to look up every time because of performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [express dynamic middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-dynamic-middleware) and use it in runtime with
 a trigger on database table.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, I found it too heavy to implement so I rather load domains from database on the app start and then keeping global variable updated by events when  app updates the database with new domains.